# Hidden checkbox input values are not sent :(

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a set of check-boxes, which under certain conditions have their DIV container element hidden.

The problem is that values from these check-boxes are not sent through `$_POST` when they are not visible. How can I force them to be sent?

Comment: how are you imposing invisibility? are you removing them from the html? visiblility:hidden? or display:none? 

and what data are contained and why are they hidden?

Comment: Checkboxes are not sent unless they are checked

Comment: I'm not hiding them directly, I'm just hiding their container with $(el).hide(). This is what is confusing me...

Comment: Are you using AJAX to post the data to the server?

Comment: yes, I'm using serialize() to get the form fields data...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not the visibility that is affecting if you can see the checkbox values. Checkbox values are not sent if the checkbox is not checked.

If the value does not exist in $_POST it has not been checked.

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Comment: So, the OP can assume a value of unchecked when the checkbox does not exist then right?

Comment: it's not that, I know that unchecked checkbox values are not sent, this is why I'm adding a hidden input field with the same name before the checkbox :) The problem is that nothing is sent if these inputs are hidden. Not even the hidden field value

Comment: does it occur in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

.hide() set the diplay to none;

visibility:hidden would work.

```
$(el).css('visibility', 'hidden');
```