# CheckedNodes posted is always null

Tags: kendo-ui

I have followed the tutorial and the documentation of kendo treeview but I have an instance where in I added hidden values into the checkbox template. The problem is when the submit button was clicked, the posted values is always null.

Here is my view

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Projects", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post,null))
{
<div class="treeview-back">

    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.UserAccountID)

    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                .Name("treeviewSiteList")
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes                        
                    .CheckChildren(true)                                                                                          
                    .TemplateId("treeview-checkbox-template")                        
                )                    
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource                        
                .Read(read => read
                        .Action("UserProjectFolderList", "Maintenance", new { useraccount_id = Model.UserAccountID }))
                )
    )

</div>

<button type="submit" class="k-button">Save</button>
}

<script id="treeview-checkbox-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
       <input type="checkbox" name="treeviewNodes[#= item.id#]" value="#= item.id # "/>                                          
       <input type="hidden" name="treeviewNodes[#= item.id #]" value="#= item.SiteID #"/>
</script>
```

Here is my view:

```
public ActionResult GetChecked(int[] treeViewNodes)
{
}
```

Comment: And how does your action method look like?

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8188464/1802671) might have anything to do (specifically the accepted answer).